# Import OpenStreetMap tiles in a Geoserver Tiled Layer

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, tiles

I've got OpenStreetMap Tiles downloaded from OSM and stored in a repository, with the structure: Zoom/X/Y.png (own of OSM).
I need to import all of them in one of Geoserver directories in order to use them as a Geoserver tiled layer.

How can I create a layer like this?

Do I need some plugin?

Can I create a generic tiled layer and after replace all tiles with mine?

Comment: perhaps this helps? https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog585/node/710

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in GeoServer.

One possibility is to run a server of some sort that can produce tiles using the WMTS standard and have [GeoServer cascade that service](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/cascaded/wmts.html).

I've never tried this but googling suggests that https://github.com/osmlab/wmts-osm might work. Alternatively, you may be able to use MapProxy or other tile server to set the tiles as WMTS.